# Do I still need a base component even if using router

Tags: angular

When using router, all tutorials show that I still need to define a root component that is passed to root module's `bootstrap` function. However, if this root's component template simply contains `<router-outlet>`, what's the purpose of this root component? Is there any way to not have it? Maybe just specify this `router-outlet` component/directive for `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is that the router adds components to `<router-outlet>`. If it doesn't find one it throws an error.

So, without a `<router-outlet>`, there is no routing.

The router also is only initialialized after the Angular2 application is bootstrapped. There is no Angular2 application without a root component.

It's also common to have static parts like menus, headers, footers, ... and only parts of the application changed by the router,
or to have multiple router-outlets that define the place where exactly the router should add components.

Comment: thanks, can we have two components on the page each with `<router-outlet>` in its template?

Comment: You can have one unnamed router-outlet and multiple named router outlets. http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: got it, thanks for the link, so is `router-outlet` a directive?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible to have no RootComponent, because it is used as you already said as a bootstrap entry point:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ RootComponent, PageNotFoundComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([ ... ]),
  ],
  bootstrap: [ RootComponent ]
})
```

RootComponent is actually used for many things, it may also

1. contain e.g. navigation and footer (static parts)
2. it can register other outlets, such as modal-outlet in some modal implementation, etc.
3. it can inject global services, because while the service is not injected anywhere it is not initialized, hence does not perform its work. This is useful for Worker-kind services, which e.g. listen to global events etc.

When the application will grow you will see the point having it.

And finally one more reason to have it - Angular docs set it up as a template of every future project, if you don't follow the default structure new developers might be confused.

What is actually the problem in having another file?

Answer (score 4):

If you know angular2 architecture, you must be knowing that **`rootcomponent`** or  **`appcomponent`** has a **`selector`** meta property in **`@Component decorator`**. Actually any **`module loader eg. webpack or systemjs`** will load file which contains  **`@NgModule decorator eg. AppModule`**  and which will further load **`rootcomponent`**.  Now, rootcompnent has a selector which matches with the tag used in **index.html** and from where you can start using angular2 features.

**`@NgModule decorator or AppModule`** file usually initiates Angular2 framework and loads **`rootcomponent`** which you can consider as an entry point to implement Angular2 functionalities. So **`rootcomponent`** is required.

*Router-outlet is a feature (generally used in rootcomponent because from rootcomponent you should be to go anywhere in the application or load different other views) to load angular2 component dynamically (according to defined routes)*